# Azure App Service Logs always shows "No deployments"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-repos

I have Private Endpoint set for Azure App Service and can load and run the app after uploading the code manually.

But when I try to set the through Deployment Center and connect Azure Repos and sync, it says "Succesfully set deployment" but there are no logs and all I see is "No deployments" and code isnt synched.

Can someone let me know what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

- What you can do is while creating the app service itself in the portal specify the deployment and then add the private endpoint.
- First add the deployment configuration

[image]

- Then you can add the endpoints

[image]

- Also, you can add the endpoints after the deployment through Networking tab

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet) on endpoint integration.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and check this.